# Docker nginx link with php-fpm

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, lumen

I am a newbie with docker since my docker-compose show no error but when i am trying access the webpage it shows defualt nginx page but not show my php application although nginx is link with php-fpm i am missing something here

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  ### PHP-FPM Container
  php-fpm:
    build: ./build/php-fpm
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www
    expose:
      - "9000"
    links:
      - mysql
      - redis

  ### NGINX Container
  nginx:
    build: ./build/nginx
    volumes:
      - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
      - .:/var/www
    ports:
      - "85:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - php-fpm

  ### Redis Container
  redis:
    image: redis
    expose:
        - "6379"

  ### MySQL Container
  mysql:
    build: ./build/mysql
    volumes:
      - ./datamysql:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - "3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
      MYSQL_USER: homestead
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

  ### Redis Container
  redis:
    image: redis
    expose:
        - "6379"


volumes:
  data:
```

Here is php-fpm  &  nginx Dockerfiles

### php-fpm

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install \
    pdo_mysql \
    pdo_pgsql

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

WORKDIR /var/www
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

### nginx

```
FROM nginx:latest

ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/
ADD site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/

RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server php-fpm:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/upstream.conf

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx"]
```

### NGINX.Conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections  2048;
  multi_accept on;
  use epoll;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 15;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  access_log on;
  error_log on;
  gzip on;
  gzip_disable "msie6";
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*;
  open_file_cache max=100;
}

daemon off;
```

### Site.Conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/site.error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,Authorization,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Location' always;

        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: try to change this `RUN echo "upstream php-upstream { server php-fpm:9000; }" > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Comment: Note that you can delete all of the `expose:` and `links:` sections in the `docker-compose.yml` with no difference in functionality.

Comment: @Adiii solution doesn't work

Comment: can you share the nginx configuration?

Comment: `root /var/www/public` - what is in `/public`?

Comment: basically this is a lumen application which is going to serve so that's why root path is  /var/www/public

Comment: OK ... what is in `/public`?